# Sort list using other list with different length

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, list-comprehension

I am attempting to resort a list based on the order in which they are listed in a dataframe, despite the dataframe column being of a greater length.

```
    enrolNo   Surname
0         1  Jones
1         2  Smith
2         3  Henderson
3         4  Kilm
4         5  Henry
5         6  Joseph


late = ['Kilm', 'Henry', 'Smith']
```

Desired output:

```
sorted_late = ['Smith', 'Kilm', 'Henry']
```

My initial attempt was to add a new column to the existing dataframe and then extract it as a list, but this seems like a very long way around. Furthermore I discovered that my attempt was not going to work due the the different lengths as stated by the error message after trying this to start with:

```
df_register['late_arrivals'] = np.where((df_register['Surname'] == late),
                        late , '')
```

Should I be using a 'for' loop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluck out the matching values from dataframe itself. No need to sort the list itself:

```
sorted_late = df[df.Surname.isin(late)].Surname.to_list()
```

If it were a list you can be clever with that too:

```
sorted_late = [master_late for master_late in master_list if master_late in late]
```

Comment: That worked like a dream. On another note, if the dataframe was a list instead, called 'master_list' for example how would that look?

Comment: Could be many possible ways via list comprehensions. One way along these lines would be: `sorted_late = [master_late for master_late in master_list  if any([late_elem==master_late for late_elem in late])]`

Comment: Consider accepting answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Sorry for leaving this unresponded to for so long. Thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the `.isin()` function?

```
df['Surename'].isin(late)
```

then you should get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify a [custom key for the sort function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {"enrolNo": 1, "Surname": "Jones"},
    {"enrolNo": 2, "Surname": "Smith"},
    {"enrolNo": 3, "Surname": "Henderson"},
    {"enrolNo": 4, "Surname": "Kilm"},
    {"enrolNo": 5, "Surname": "Henry"},
    {"enrolNo": 6, "Surname": "Joseph"},
])

# set Surname as index so we can access enrolNo by it
df = df.set_index('Surname')  

# now you can access enrolNo by Surname
assert df.loc['Kilm']['enrolNo'] == 4

# define the list to be sorted    
late = ['Kilm', 'Henry', 'Smith']

# Sort late by enrolNo as listed in the dataframe 
late_sorted = sorted(late, key=lambda n: df.loc[n]['enrolNo'])
# ['Smith', 'Kilm', 'Henry']
```